# android ViewModelScopeコルーチンでメインスレッドを停止する方法は？

Tags: android

androidのViewModelScopeを使ってサーバーのファイルにアクセスするアプリとして下記コードを書きました。
サーバーのファイルにアクセスするメソッドとしてSmbViewModel.ktのconnectSmb1()を使えばうまく動きますが、connectSmb2()ではconnectSmb2()がfalseを返して失敗します。
connectSmb1()では、サーバーファイルにアクセスするワーカースレッドでの作業終了後、メインスレッドにsleep()で5秒間の停止を入れています。
connectSmb2()は、ワーカースレッドでの作業終了を待ってメインスレッドが動くようにするつもりでasync(Dispatchers.IO){}.await()を入れてみたものです。
sleep()を使わずに動作するコードをお教えください。

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import PACKAGE.smbclient2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    val DOMAIN: String = "192.168.1.1"
    val SMBROOT: String = "/SMB/SERVER/FILE/"
    val USER: String = "FOO"
    val PASSWORD: String = "BAR"
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // prepare for connecting SMB server
        var smbUrl = "smb://" + DOMAIN + SMBROOT

        // get ViewModel for SmbConnection
        val smbViewModelFactory = SmbViewModelFactory(USER, PASSWORD, DOMAIN, smbUrl)
        val smbViewModel: SmbViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, smbViewModelFactory).get(SmbViewModel::class.java)

        // connect SMB server
        if ( !smbViewModel.connectSmb2() ) {
            finishAndRemoveTask()
        }

        /*
         * get data in SMB server
         */
        // Create the observer which updates the UI.
        val pathObserver = Observer<String> { sPath ->
            binding.tvSmbPath.text = sPath
        }
        val sizeObserver = Observer<Long> { sSize ->
            binding.tvSmbSize.text = sSize.toString()
        }

        smbViewModel.smbPath.observe(this, pathObserver)
        smbViewModel.smbSize.observe(this, sizeObserver)
    }
}
```

SmbViewModel.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import jcifs.CIFSContext
import jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration
import jcifs.context.BaseContext
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.*

class SmbViewModel(val user: String, val password: String, val domain: String, val smbUrl: String): ViewModel() {

    // LiveDataを設定する
    private val _smbPath: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }
    val smbPath: LiveData<String>
        get() = _smbPath

    private val _smbSize: MutableLiveData<Long> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Long>()
    }
    val smbSize: LiveData<Long>
        get() = _smbSize

    /*
     * SMBサーバーへの接続
     */

    // SMBサーバーへの接続例1
    fun connectSmb1(): Boolean {
        var retBool: Boolean = false

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val prop = Properties()  // java.util.Properties
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.minVersion", "SMB202")
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.maxVersion", "SMB300")
            val bc = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
            val creds = NtlmPasswordAuthentication(bc, domain, user, password)
            val auth: CIFSContext = bc.withCredentials(creds)
            val smb = SmbFile(smbUrl, auth)
            if (smb.exists()) {
                // LiveDataにSMBサーバーからのデータをセットする
                _smbPath.postValue(smb.path)
                _smbSize.postValue(smb.length())
                retBool = true
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        return retBool
    }


    // SMBサーバーへの接続例2
    fun connectSmb2(): Boolean {
        var retBool: Boolean = false

        viewModelScope.launch{
            val retAsync = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val prop = Properties()  // java.util.Properties
                prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.minVersion", "SMB202")
                prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.maxVersion", "SMB300")
                val bc = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
                val creds = NtlmPasswordAuthentication(bc, domain, user, password)
                val auth: CIFSContext = bc.withCredentials(creds)
                val smb = SmbFile(smbUrl, auth)
                if (smb.exists()) {
                    // LiveDataにSMBサーバーからのデータをセットする
                    _smbPath.postValue(smb.path)
                    _smbSize.postValue(smb.length())
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
            retBool = retAsync.await()
        }
        return retBool
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

SmbViewModelFactory.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class SmbViewModelFactory(val user: String, val password: String, val domain: String, val smbUrl: String): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return SmbViewModel(user, password, domain, smbUrl) as T
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

自己レスです。
メソッドの中でlaunch{}内のデータをlaunch外に渡すにはLiveDataを使うしかないことが https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67343540/how-to-send-the-result-of-viewmodelscope-launch-as-the-return-value-of-a-funct に書かれていました。
次のコードで実現できました。
ワーカースレッドのlaunch{}内で、LiveDataのisConnectedSmbに処理結果をセットし、メインスレッドでisConnectedSmbの値をobserveメソッドで取得しています。

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import net.sytes.rokkosan.smbclient2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    val DOMAIN: String = "192.168.1.1"
    val SMBROOT: String = "/SMB/SERVER/FILE/"
    val USER: String = "FOO"
    val PASSWORD: String = "BAR"
    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // prepare for connecting SMB server
        val smbUrl = "smb://" + DOMAIN + SMBROOT

        // get ViewModel for SmbConnection
        val smbViewModelFactory = SmbViewModelFactory(USER, PASSWORD, DOMAIN, smbUrl)
        val smbViewModel: SmbViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, smbViewModelFactory).get(SmbViewModel::class.java)

        // connect SMB server
        smbViewModel.connectSmb()
        val isConnectedObserver = Observer<Boolean> { isConnected ->
            if (!isConnected) {
                finishAndRemoveTask()
            }
        }
        smbViewModel.isConnectedSmb.observe(this,isConnectedObserver)

        /*
         * get data in SMB server
         */
        // Create the observer which updates the UI.
        val pathObserver = Observer<String> { sPath ->
            // Update the UI
            binding.tvSmbPath.text = sPath
        }
        val sizeObserver = Observer<Long> { sSize ->
            // Update the UI
            binding.tvSmbSize.text = sSize.toString()
        }

        smbViewModel.smbPath.observe(this, pathObserver)
        smbViewModel.smbSize.observe(this, sizeObserver)
    }
}
```

SmbViewModel.kt

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration
import jcifs.context.BaseContext
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthenticator
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.*

class SmbViewModel(val user: String, val password: String, val domain: String, val smbUrl: String): ViewModel() {

    // LiveDataを設定する
    private val _smbPath: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }
    val smbPath: LiveData<String>
        get() = _smbPath

    private val _smbSize: MutableLiveData<Long> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Long>()
    }
    val smbSize: LiveData<Long>
        get() = _smbSize

    private val _isConnectedSmb = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val isConnectedSmb: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _isConnectedSmb

    // SMBサーバーへの接続
    fun connectSmb() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val prop = Properties()  // java.util.Properties
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.minVersion", "SMB202")
            prop.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.maxVersion", "SMB300")
            val baseCxt = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(prop))
            val auth =
                baseCxt.withCredentials(NtlmPasswordAuthenticator(domain, user, password))
            val smb = SmbFile(smbUrl, auth)
            if (smb.exists()) {
                // LiveDataにSMBサーバーからのデータをセットする
                _smbPath.postValue(smb.path)
                _smbSize.postValue(smb.length())
                _isConnectedSmb.postValue(true)
            } else {
                _isConnectedSmb.postValue(false)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

自己レスです。
メインスレッドを停止するのではなく、「ワーカースレッドでの処理結果が出次第、Activityで所要の処理を行う」という観点が必要でした。
ワーカースレッドの結果をLiveDataでActivityに渡し、Observerでいろいろと処理すればよいです。
下記参考ページを掲載します。
https://rasumus.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/09/03/221016